# bin/python3: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

I just made a new django project, pushed it to git and now I am trying to go deploy it using Digital ocean.

I installed all the needful things like pip, python etc. but I am not able to make the `python manage.py runserver` work.

((g-v) is my virtualenv so that is not the problem.)

It is throwing this error:

```
(g-v) root@ubuntu-s-4vcpu-8gb-blr1-01:/home/g-v/src# python manage.py runserver
  File "manage.py", line 14
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I read a few posts that recommended trying out `python3 manage.py runserver` but when I try that, I get this error:

```
(g-v) root@ubuntu-s-4vcpu-8gb-blr1-01:/home/g-v/src# python3 manage.py runserver
-bash: /home/g-v/bin/python3: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

My `pip list` command outputs:

```
(g-v) root@ubuntu-s-4vcpu-8gb-blr1-01:/home/g-v/src# pip list
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Package                       Version
----------------------------- ----------
astroid                       1.6.6
autopep8                      1.4.4
backports.functools-lru-cache 1.5
certifi                       2019.6.16
configparser                  3.7.4
Django                        1.11.23
enum34                        1.1.6
futures                       3.2.0
isort                         4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy             1.4.1
mccabe                        0.6.1
pip                           19.2.2
pipenv                        2018.11.26
pkg-resources                 0.0.0
pycodestyle                   2.5.0
Pygments                      2.4.2
pylint                        1.9.4
pytz                          2019.2
setuptools                    41.1.0
singledispatch                3.4.0.3
six                           1.12.0
typing                        3.7.4
virtualenv                    16.7.3
virtualenv-clone              0.5.3
wheel                         0.33.6
wrapt                         1.11.2
```

Comment: At first sight, there seems to be something wrong with the `python3` binary.

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix that? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Not sure how you've set up your DO droplet, but they do have pre-configured Django droplets - I would imagine using one of those should do away with any complex config issues. I've only run a few tests with them, but I had no issues with using their Django droplet ...

Comment: Here's something that worked for me: cd to the root directory of the project, deactivate virtualenv, reinstall python3 and run `python3 manage.py runserver` without doing `source bin/activate`.

Answer (score 0):

I observed such an error when I forgot to turn venv.

Try `source ./path-to-venv/bin/activate` and try again `manage.py runserver` command.

Comment: Yeah, that did not work. I ran `source bin/activate` (as I said in the question). Thanks for trying to help! :D